# How to Stick the arrow icon to line

Tags: html, css

Am trying to make a border with CSS like below which has an small triangle icon CSS which needs to be exactly centered to the border line of the div. If i use `float:right` or left the arrow icon goes to either end of the border line, can i make it to center and if possible stick to border line as responsive design.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.arrow-down { 
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid rgba(30, 7, 7, 0);
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <p>This text is centered.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>

  <div class="center">
    <p>This second text is centered.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>

  <div class="center">
    <p>This third text is centered.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `margin-left: 50%` to bring it to center, and set `margin-top: -3px` to move it over the border of the previous element.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
  
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid rgba(30, 7, 7, 0);
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #f00;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p>This text is centered.</p>
</div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>

<div class="center">
  <p>This second text is centered.</p>
</div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>

<div class="center">
  <p>This third text is centered.</p>
</div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS Positioning** for this, and use CSS's `calc()` function to adjust it from the top. i.e. `100% - 3px` (which is your border width)

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.div-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid green;
}

.arrow-down{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 3px);
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid rgba(30, 7, 7, 0);
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div-container">
  <div class="center">
    <p>This text is centered.</p>
  </div>  
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</div>

<div class="div-container">
  <div class="center">
    <p>This second text is centered.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</div>

<div class="div-container">
  <div class="center">
    <p>This third text is centered.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Place the arrow in the  `.center` and specify its location with
>   `position:absolute;` `top: 100%;` `left: 48%;`

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
  position: relative;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid rgba(30, 7, 7, 0);
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 48%;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p>This text is centered.</p>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</div>
<div class="center">
  <p>This second text is centered.</p>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</div>
<div class="center">
  <p>This third text is centered.</p>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.arrow-down { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 45%;
  border-left: 10px solid rgba(30, 7, 7, 0);
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="center">
    <p>This text is centered.</p>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <p>This second text is centered.</p>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <p>This third text is centered.</p>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Best possible** way to achieve this by using  `margin: 0 auto;` and also stick to border line as responsive design. `margin: 0 auto;` means :

```
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
   .arrow-down{ width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid rgba(30, 7, 7, 0);
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #f00;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
  <p>This text is centered.</p>
</div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>

<div class="center">
  <p>This second text is centered.</p>
</div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>

<div class="center">
  <p>This third text is centered.</p>
</div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the HTML a little.
In the present one, the arrow is positioned absolute and it can be perfectly center aligned in any size of the container div.center

```css
.center {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
  position: relative;
}
.arrow-down { 
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid rgba(30, 7, 7, 0);
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #f00;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <p>This text is centered.</p>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <p>This second text is centered.</p>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <p>This third text is centered.</p>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
  position : relative;
  margin-bottom : 30px;
}

.center:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid rgba(30, 7, 7, 0);
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #f00;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p>This text is centered.</p>
</div>

<div class="center">
  <p>This second text is centered.</p>
</div>

<div class="center">
  <p>This third text is centered.</p>
</div>
```